# How do I translate "File.open" to be S3 compatible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

I have this line..

```
@organization.search_image = File.open(@photo.photo.path(:original))
```

Except that 's looking for something local, and all my photos are on S3 now. How would I translate that to opening a file on S3?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you should do is download/stream the image in S3 and write it to a new file then use the new file.

```
open('newpic.png', 'w') do |file|
    S3Object.stream('pic.png', 'bucket_name') do |chunk|
      file.write chunk
    end
end

#Write the streamed file to newpic.png then use newpic.png.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options that come to mind:

1. Use the [S3 Ruby bindings](http://amazon.rubyforge.org/) and access your data using the **S3** provided abstractions.
2. Continue with the filesystem abstraction but bind **S3** to a local proxy filesystem using [FUSE](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon) which is available for *nix/OSX (but not for Windows as far as I know) making this approach less generally applicable. This is probably less efficient than option 1 too.

Comment: While S3 Ruby bindings works, I can't seem to translate that into something I could use on my local box, let along to resend back up to the server. I found out about Right_Aws, and wrote a script out for that but it doesn't handle writing and re adding to the server.